# AJAX response shows up, then disappears in Chrome (July 2017)

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, response

I have an issue that I think is related to a recent update in Google Chrome.  Until July 2017 it worked without a hitch.  I just tried it with Microsoft Edge and it works there, no problem.

On Chrome, I make an AJAX request to update the list with 6 new products.  They show up, but then an instant later they disappear.  Actually, they are still there, since if I hover over them, some information shows up.  If I highlight them (with the mouse or CTRL+A) and click elsewhere, most of the time they stay visible.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?  Sorry I'm not posting code, I don't even know which part of it I would need to post.  As I said, I doubt the problem is in the code, since I haven't changed it in the last six months or more and this problem showed up about a month ago (at the same time on more than one computer).

Comment: Do you have version 60.0.x of Chrome? (check by visiting chrome://version in a chrome browser). If you do, try to scroll out and then in again (using CTRL and scroll, or CTRL and +/-). Does the content appear?

Comment: Yes, I have the newest version of Chrome (60.0.3112).  And yes, the content appears when I scroll out or in, even better than when I highlight it.  The problem is that this happens on our online catalog that is visible to everyone (and I cannot really ask each one of our clients to CTRL and +/- every time they click somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an error in Chrome (from V60) where Chrome *forgets* to re-render elements under certain conditions.

A way to fix it using CSS, is to use `translateZ(0)` to force chrome to rerender the content.

```
.your-element {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: It took me a few minutes to find the correct element to re-render, but now it works.  Thank you very much, Daniel, for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help - feel free to accept this answer :)